# How many layers of a neural network are needed to get 0 training error?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Is there a general formula for this? I read

(no of inputs + no of outputs)^0.5 + (1 to 10). to fix the constant value (last part, 0 to 10), use trial and error and find the optimal no of hidden layer neurons for the min MSE.

but I was wondering if there was a more specific formula.

**Edit:** Quote read from https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_decide_the_number_of_hidden_layers_and_nodes_in_a_hidden_layer

Comment: Why would you want to get training error equal to zero?! This would produce a very bad, overfitting model.

Comment: I agree wiith @Tim.

Answer (score 4):

One hidden layer is enough to achieve an arbitrarily low training error, as stated by the  [Universal approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem):

> In the mathematical theory of artificial neural networks, the universal approximation theorem states that a feed-forward network with a single hidden layer containing a finite number of neurons (i.e., a multilayer perceptron), can approximate continuous functions on compact subsets of Rn, under mild assumptions on the activation function. The theorem thus states that simple neural networks can represent a wide variety of interesting functions when given appropriate parameters; however, it does not touch upon the algorithmic learnability of those parameters.